# How to access specific class attribute in less mixin?

Tags: css, less, mixins, less-mixins

I have .aClass

```
.aClass {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}
```

In .anotherClass I would like to calculate a width value based on the value of the width attribute in .aClass.

```
.anotherClass {
 width: .aClass.width
}
```

The above example does not work.

I couldn´t find anything in the less docs. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am searching for this, too. Not mixins, but this reuse of earlier class property.

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable at the top of code

```
@width: 10px
```

Then,

```
.aClass {
 width: @width;
 height: 20px;
}

.anotherClass {
 width: @width;
}
```

Comment: Are less variables with @ sign?